# XML: Question mark at the end of an element

Tags: xml

xml newbie here. i have an xml file that starts with the following line:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!ELEMENT Family (numberofchildren,Childrensnames?)>
```

i don't quite understand the second question mark in the above code. Could somebody please tell me its function? im vaguely guessing it has something to do with the  preceding element being optional.   i have been reading some threads about process instructions. though im not really sure if that answers my question.

thx
mel

UPDATE: it was the 3rd question mark i meant. thx for the answers

Comment: Actually, I tnink you're asking about thd third question mark, and yes,"optional" is one way to think about it.

Comment: thx! and yea ur right :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A?
>   A must occur zero or one time.

From the HTML 4 guide to [reading DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3)

Comment: can you please elaborate? Does that mean the xml file Family either has an element called childrensnames or doesnt. did i get that right? thx

Comment: It means that `<Family>` can have 0 `<Childrennames>` children or 1 `<Childrennames>` child, but not any other number.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean the second question mark rather than the third: The XML Declaration uses the same syntax as a Processing Instruction. It starts with `<?` and ends with `?>`.

(If present, the XML Declaration must also be the very first thing in the document, with no whitespace or comments before it.)